# How to make DSolve express constants in terms of the unknown function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

If I do

```
DSolve[y'[x] == y[x], y[x], x]
```

Mathematica returns

```
{{y[x] -> E^x C[1]}}
```

Is there a way to have it return this instead?

```
{{y[x] -> E^x y[0]}}
```

Comment: `sol = DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == y0}, y[x], x]`

Comment: `DSolve[y'[x] == y[x], y[x], x] /. C[1] -> y[0]` ?